# Does a dead body controlled by a magical mushroom entity count as undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead

My players will soon be going into a dungeon that is an old abandoned dwarven mine. I plan to have there be a mushroom-like entity or something that has taken over the mine and is the reason the mine is abandoned. (invaded and killed a few of the miners)

My question is if the mushroom entity uses its spores to grow fungus on the dead bodies and control them would they count as undead for the purpose of a cleric's Turn Undead feature?

Comment: Is this an official, pre-existing mushroom or is this homebrew you’ve created or found? If this is homebrew then we can’t answer that considering we’re not the ones that designed the abilities for the mushroom so we have no idea how it works. If this is an official monster then please [edit] in a reference for it so we know what we’re looking at.

Comment: Also, welcome to the site. Don't forget to take the [tour] and check out the [help].

Comment: Do you mean myconid spore servants? (MM 230)

Comment: @Szega Those are plants, not undead. But it does seem to be the kind of theme OP wants to go for.

Comment: @Theik I am aware, but I am not sure OP is. The description is really close to them.

Comment: @Szega It sounds more like they're looking to create a new type of undead-creating mushroom and asking if it's possible, but the question makes it hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

## Possibly!

First of all, this is a question only a DM can answer, because such a creature could also just be labeled as a plant, a monstrosity or anything else the DM feels like. But, there is a precedent!

The Druid of Spores from the Ravnica campaign setting has the ability to use its aura of spores to revive creatures that die as zombies. For all game statistics, these count as undead, so turn undead would work on them.

So as far as Wizards of the Coast is concerned, it seems like mushroom zombies being undead is perfectly okay in D&D as far as RAW rules go.

Answer (score 1):

## Players will probably think the creature is undead

There are no real rules for how to classify homebrew monsters, you can label creatures however you want. However you seem to think the mushroom-animated-corpse is undead, and I agree, so the players will probably think that too.

[Dictionary.com via google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aundead) says undead is:

> (of a fictional being, especially a vampire) technically dead but still animate.

Well, a corpse controlled by a mushroom is certainly technically dead, and certainly still animate. So it is understandable why you, I, and possibly your players, will think that the corpse is undead.

### But you could undermine their preconception

Instead of playing to what they expect, you could make the mushrooms able to animate anything, piles of rocks, abandoned pickaxes, etc. To the mushrooms everything is just objects. You would have to be careful to stop it from being a cheap trick. If at first the party thinks they are fighting undead, only for them to realise that Turn Undead doesn't work, and that these are mushrooms that happen to be growing in corpses, that could be fun!